# iTerm2: What is the best way to compare / diff two panes (like vimdiff)?

Tags: compare, iterm2, pane, vimdiff

I would like to **compare two panes** in **iTerm2**, like I can do it in **vimdiff**.
(Or is it the best way ***to do it in vimdiff***, not using iTerm2 panes??)

– I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

– And how can I **search** the [iTerm documentation](https://iterm2.com/documentation.html) – – only with help of Google?